# What is the difference between SPI(Serial Peripheral Interface) and GSB(General purpose Serial Bus)?

Tags: embedded, spi

I'm a newbie in embedded programming.
Now I'm trying to understand a datasheet for Telechips 8001S. 
What is the difference between SPI(Serial Peripheral Interface) and GSB(General purpose Serial Bus)?

Thank you.

Comment: one is a generic convention/standard and the other is a specific implementation by a chip or ip vendor (for spi, uart, i2c, etc)?

Comment: You should provide links.

Comment: @dwelch: Actually, SPI is mostly the signals (and it is not a standard - or can you provide any ISO/IEEE code?). For anything else, including framing or bits/symbol, even shift-direction (LSB/MSB first), there is no common agreement. For GSB: do you have an actual Idea what that is (I do not)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus  developed by motorola and has become a de facto standard.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C like spi, you may or may not agree that it is a standard but also various vendors interpret it differently and implement it in not really the same way.  I couldnt find even that telechips much less the gsb thing but based on what various chip vendors call their generic-ish serial peripherals that do more than one protocol, my guess is that is what it is.  but I dont actually know either

Comment: @dwelch: I know SPI very well, since I work with this on veraious MCUs for decades. However, as there are no common agreements about timing, how to handle SS, etc. and there is no true _standard_, putting it in quotation marks would be the correct way. Never mind! The second link you provided is about I2C, which uses a completely different transmission format/protocol. That is completely unrelated to SPI. They only have synchrous bit-serial transfers in common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google is your friend...

Telechips GPSB appears to be their spi implementation (and one or more other serial protocols) master or slave with dma.  Spi is the protocol, call it a standard or not but there are a large quantity of devices that support it, GPSB is the logic/peripheral in the chip that you can use to connect to spi masters or slaves (you can always bit bang on gpio of course).  Looks to have dma and probably other features.

I didnt find the 8001 nor the 8010 docs, but did find one that was enough to understand.

On some ti products you may find the USI, universal serial interface, the name for their uart, spi and i2c peripheral.

Some ftdi chips have MPSSE, which can be programmed to implement quite a few protocols, jtag, spi, i2c, mdio, roll your own.

Other vendors may simply call the peripheral UART, SPI, I2C.

Its just a name that marketing or engineering or a combination of the two at that company chose for the peripheral within the chip.

Comment: Hmm, I just find a block-diagram and there is "SPI" mentioned, but noting like "GPSB". Noting else to be found on that crappy website (does not even work properly in firefox - Flash navigation? No way!).

Comment: Note: You are massively confusion SPI, U(S)ART and I2C. These are very different serial transmission links. UART for instance is asynchronous. Please do not mix them! And no vendor will use these names interchangeably. There are only different names for I2C as that name is/was protected by Philips (now NXP) who developed it. The other names are never used as synonyms for I2C.

Comment: not massively confused in anyway.  they are low speed simple serial protocols that depending on the vendor are supported in the same logic block/peripheral.  no they are not the same protocols as each other not interchangable in anyway, never said that never meant that.  I know y ou like to read standards but do you actually read datasheets and actually use these peripherals?

Comment: You wrote vendors use SPI, I2C and UAT as synonyms: "Other vendors may simply call the peripheral UART, SPI, I2C.". That implies they are interchangably. That is just not true (I cannot read your thoughts, so I cannot see what you meant).

Comment: "actually read datasheets and actually use these peripherals": No, I programmed them just without any documentation for decades, developed hardware with them (and many other interfaces), implemented such interfaces in FPGAs/VHDL, etc. All without reading a single word of datasheet (note: for larger MCUs, the datasheets do not contain specs for the peripherals. This is in reference manuals/family guides, user's guides, etc.).